# Iterate two arraylists and put key-value to map more elegantly

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, java-8

In my method for starters I make sure the two ArrayLists have the same size, otherwise I throw an exception. The solution I use to iterate two ArrayLists and put the key-value pair in a map works fine, but I also find it not very elegant or up to date.

In this method I am filling a map that will later be used with the Apache freemarker library.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String placeHolder;
String value;
for (int i = 0; i < placeHolderList.size(); i++) {
    placeHolder = placeHolderList.get(i);
    value = valueList.get(i);

    map.put(placeHolder, value);
}
```

What is a more elegant and efficient way to do this in Java 8?

Comment: Don't declare `String placeHolder;` and `String value;` before the `for` loop. With the Stream API, no real elegant solution, just use an `IntStream` over the indexes, and `toMap` collector. See the Oracle tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this could do the trick:

```
List<String> placeHolderList = Arrays.asList("key1", "key2");
List<Object> valueList = Arrays.asList("value1", "value2");

Map<String, Object> result = IntStream.range(0, placeHolderList.size())
    .boxed()
    .collect(toMap(placeHolderList::get, valueList::get));

System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
{key1=value1, key2=value2}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [@NicolasFilotto answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37204618/4105457) you need to iterate over the indices but there is no need to box the index itself.

```
Map<String, Object> result = IntStream.range(0, placeHolderList.size())
                              .collect(HashMap::new, 
                               (map, i) -> map.put(placeHolderList.get(i), valueList.get(i)),
                               Map::putAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not using java 8. then try this:

```
    List<String> keyList = Arrays.asList("1", "2");
    List<String> valList = Arrays.asList("one", "two");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < keyList.size(); i++) {
        map.put(keyList.get(i), valList.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```